# torch cv.warpPerspective: resulting image is black

Tags: opencv, torch

I am using cv.warpPerspective(), where the transformation is obtained from cv.getPerspectiveTransform().

```
local img = image.load(file_name)
local w, h = img:size[3], img:size[2]
local src = torch.FloatTensor(4,2)
src[1][1], src[1][2] = 1, 1
src[2][1], src[2][2] = h, 1
src[3][1], src[3][2] = h, w
src[4][1], src[4][2] = 1,w
local dst = torch.FloatTensor(4,2)
dst[1][1], dst[1][2] = src[1][1], src[1][2]
dst[2][1], dst[2][2] = src[2][1], src[2][2]
dst[3][1], dst[3][2] = src[3][1], src[3][2]
dst[4][1], dst[4][2] = torch.floor(src[4][1]/2), torch.floor(src[4][2]/2)

local M = cv.getPerspectiveTransform{src, dst}
local new_h = torch.max(dst[{{},{1}}]) - torch.min(dst[{{},{1}}]) + 1
local new_w = torch.max(dst[{{},{2}}]) - torch.min(dst[{{},{2}}]) + 1
local warped_img = torch.FloatTensor(3, new_h, new_w)
cv.warpPerspective{src=img, dst=warped_img, M=M:float()}
```

However `warped_img` is a black image (i.e. 0 at every entry).

Could someone please suggest what I did wrong? Many thanks!

Comment: For starters your coordinates are in `(y,x)` order but for `cv.getPerspectiveTransform` they should be in `(x,y)` order, at least in Python and C++ implementations. Not sure if that's the main issue.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds thank you for the comment! I think the coordinates are in `(x,y)` order, since my x-axis points downwards (i.e. the direction of height) and y-axis points to the right (i.e. the direction of width). Moreover, I used the result of `cv.getPerspectiveTransform` in another method and it worked correctly, so I guess the problem is not the calculation of the transformation matrix.